# How do I remove a child later? (cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I added a child like this inside of a CCLayer:

```
[self addChild:object1];
```

Later on I want to remove that object from the children. Ummm so how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question leads me to believe you don't know the cocos2d API reference: 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/

To remove object1 simply use this:

```
[self removeChild:object1 cleanup:YES];
```

If you don't keep a reference of object1 around you can remove it by tag, which means you'll have to give it a tag first:

```
object1.tag = 123; // just any arbitrary number
[self addChild:object1];
```

To remove it:

```
[self removeChildByTag:123 cleanup:YES];
```

I've added this Q&A to my cocos2d FAQ, please find more details to this answer here:
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/cocos2d-iphone-faq/learn-cocos2d-public-content/manual/cocos2d-general/14824-how-to-remove-a-child-from-the-nodescenelayer

Comment: Hey nice. Did not know about tags. Happiness increased.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [removeChild](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a409c8fa79c0c6f26c7d84145f75d78ad) method?